# NAudio: WaveBadFormat Exception while initializing WaveOut with BufferedWaveProvider

Tags: c#, exception, audio, naudio, codec

I am trying to playback audio with NAudio, using `WaveOut` initialized with a `BufferedWaveProvider`. An `UdpClient` receives the audio packets in a seperate Thread and writes them into the `BufferedWaveProvider` via `AddSamples()`.

So far everything works as it should.

Unfortunately, when switching the device (setting the `DeviceId` property of `WaveOut` according to the selected device and re-initializing `WaveOut`), a [`MmException`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyPaH.png) occurs.

Somehow the error only occurs, when the `WaveFormat` of the `BufferedWaveProvider` is set to any A- or ULawFormat (e. g. with `WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000, 1)`). When setting it to `new WaveFormat(8000, 8, 1)` switching the audio device works perfectly fine, but then the received audio doesen't get playbacked correctly (because it's sent with G711A Codec => ALawFormat needed).

Here is the example code (for demonstration purposes I am using a `WaveFileReader` instead of the `UdpClient` here):

```
public class MainViewModel {
    private BufferedWaveProvider _WaveProvider;
    private WaveOut _WaveOut;

    public ObservableCollection<string> AllAudioDevices { get; set; }

    private string _SelectedAudioDevice;
    public string SelectedAudioDevice {
        get => _SelectedAudioDevice;
        set {
            _SelectedAudioDevice = value;
            OnSelectedAudioDeviceChanged(value);
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel() {
        _WaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(8000, 1));
        _WaveOut = new WaveOut();

        AllAudioDevices = LoadAllAudioDevices();
        SelectedAudioDevice = AllAudioDevices[0];
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> LoadAllAudioDevices() {
        var allAudioDevices = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < WaveOut.DeviceCount; i++) {
            allAudioDevices.Add(WaveOut.GetCapabilities(i).ProductName);
        }

        return allAudioDevices;
    }

    private void OnSelectedAudioDeviceChanged(string newAudioDevice) {
        _WaveOut.Stop();

        _WaveOut = new WaveOut();
        _WaveOut.DeviceNumber = AllAudioDevices.IndexOf(newAudioDevice);
        _WaveOut.Init(_WaveProvider);
        _WaveOut.Play();

        new Thread(ReceiveAudio).Start();
    }

    private void ReceiveAudio() {
        var reader = new WaveFileReader(@"D:\temp\test.wav");

        byte[] readBytes;
        int readCount;

        do {
            readBytes = new byte[1000];
            readCount = reader.Read(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);

            if (readCount == 0) {
                break;
            }

            _WaveProvider.AddSamples(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not all Codec are the same.  The chip used in the machine may not support the mode, and/or the driver may not support the mode.  Use Device manager to check the driver and IC used on machine.  I usually find the IC being used and then download the driver from the manufacturer.  Not the generic Microsoft Driver or the PC manufacturer install driver.  Get the latest from the manufacturer of the IC (chip set).

Answer (score 0):

You can't open an output device directly using u-law or a-law. You need to convert to 16 bit PCM. Fortunately its very easy to do that in NAudio - just use the `MuLawDecoder` or `ALawDecoder` classes. You'll also find in the NAudio GitHub repo a [network chat demo](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudioDemo/NetworkChatDemo) that shows a very similar use case to what you're trying to achieve.